# Get the index given a complex condition in a column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

I'm trying to get the index given the following conditions in the column 'Product':

- That the value is a string.
- That the value doesn't contain a comma.

This is what I'm trying now:

```
product_list = []

for i in data['Product']: 
    if(isinstance(i, str)):
        if "," not in i:
            product_list.append(data['Product'].index)
```

If the value of the cell is a string, and there isn't a comma, append the index to the list. But I can't get the index this way.

If the condition were easier, just by looking up by one type of product, I could have obtained it this way:

```
data.index[data['Products']=='A'].tolist()
```

Is there any similar way to do it?

Comment: Please don't include images of data, but instead include a text representation of the data, or the code to generate the data to test your code with. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Perhaps `data[~data.Product.str.contains(",")]`?

Comment: What do you mean by *If the value of the cell is a string*? A number like 123 in your `Product` column will be a string not a number.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)